# Evento onchange no Input type="text" em uma aplicação Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Blazor e consegui fazer um InputText juntamente com um button realizar uma pesquisa em uma api criada por intermédio de scafolding com Entity Frameworks.

Segue simples formulário abaixo.

```
<label>Hello @motorista !!</label>
<input type="text" @bind-value="motorista" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="PesquisaMotorista">Click me</button>

@code {

    private string motorista = null;

    Veiculo[] veiculos { get; set; }

    protected async Task PesquisaMotorista()
    {
        veiculos = await http.GetJsonAsync<Veiculo[]>($"api/veiculos/motorista/{motorista}");
    }
}
```

Gostaria de utilizar o evento onchange no input, para não mais necessitar do button do formulário acima.

Abaixo segue o mesmo formulário sem o button e com o evento oninput que não esta funcionando conforme o evento onchange.

**Como faço para utilizar no exemplo abaixo o evento onchange?**

```
 <label>Hello @motorista !!</label>
 <input type="text" @bind-value="motorista" @oninput="PesquisaMotorista" />
 @code {

    private string motorista = null;

    Veiculo[] veiculos { get; set; }

    protected async Task PesquisaMotorista()
    {
        veiculos = await http.GetJsonAsync<Veiculo[]>($"api/veiculos/motorista/{motorista}");
    }
 }
```

**Alguns testes realizados até o momento**

Com onclick digito o texto e dou um clique no input ai a pesquisa é realizada

```
<input type="text" @bind-value="motorista" @bind-value:event="oninput" @onclick="PesquisaMotorista" />
```

Com onchange digito o texto e dou um enter, ai a pesquisa é realizada

```
<input type="text" @bind-value="motorista" @bind-value:event="oninput" @onchange="PesquisaMotorista" />
```

**Solução obtida com o evento onkeyup**

```
<input type="text" @bind-value="motorista" @bind-value:event="oninput" @onkeyup="PesquisaMotorista" />
```

Comment: Você está utilizando algum framework js? tipo jquery?

Comment: Não estou utilizando nenhum tipo de frameworks js e jquery - estou procurando usar os conceitos do Blazor, tem que utilizar alguma coisa ?

Comment: <input type="text" @bind-value="motorista" @bind-value:event="oninput" @onchange="PesquisaMotorista" /> - neste exemplo o evento onchange esta funcionando mas modo estranho, temos que digitar primeiro um texto e dar enter, ai realiza a pesquisa

Comment: Solução obtida com o evento onkeyup, veja exemplo na atualização do post de perguntas

Comment: coloca sua solução em uma resposta, e marca a sua própria resposta como a solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obtive resultado com o evento onkeyup**

```
<input type="text" 
       @bind-value="motorista" 
       @bind-value:event="oninput" 
       @onkeyup="PesquisaMotorista" />

@code {

private string motorista = null;

Veiculo[] veiculos { get; set; }

protected async Task PesquisaMotorista()
{
   //Acessa a rota personalizada na VeiculosController
    veiculos = await http.GetJsonAsync<Veiculo[]>($"api/veiculos/motorista/{motorista}");
}
```

}

**Api da VeiculosController**

```
// GET: api/Veiculos
[HttpGet("motorista/{motorista}")]//Rota personalizada
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Veiculo>>> GetVeiculos(string motorista)
{
      return await _context.Veiculos
                   .Where(v => v.Motorista.Contains(motorista))
                   .ToListAsync();
}
```